# Can't get Magento2's .media-width() LESS mixin to work

Tags: magento2, less, mixins

I'm trying to use Magento2's `.media-width()` mixin.  I followed the instructions from the [devdocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/responsive-web-design/rwd_css.html) and added the mixin in my theme like this:

```
.logo img {
  width: 125px;
  height: 29px;
  .media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__m) {
    width: 250px;
    height: 58px;
  }
}
```

Only the CSS outside of the `.media-width()` is being generated.  Nothing within it is being generated.  Am I missing something.

**UPDATE**

Following the advice of @circlesix I did not nest the media query, but still I'm having some trouble.

```
.logo img {
  width: 125px;
  height: 29px;
}
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__m) {
  .logo img {
    width: 177px;
    height: 41px;
  }
}
```

My desktop rule in the media query is being overruled by the first rule for `.logo img` as it is defined later in styles-l.css.
[image]

Interestingly I don't see the rule I defined within the `media-width()` mixin defined anywhere within styles-m.css.  So perhaps I need to use the `media-width()` for both desktop & mobile views and only define common properties outside of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I discovered a little more about this but as @circlesix pointed out it's not possible to use these LESS mixins nested like this.

Furthermore if you look at the `<head>` section of Magento you'll notice that the *styles-l.css* is loaded after the mobile styles, i.e. *styles-m.css*.

```
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="http://example.com/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/styles-m.css" />
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="screen and (min-width: 768px)" href="http://example.com/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/styles-l.css" />
```

So *styles-l.css* is only loaded on screens 768px and over in width, saving mobile devices from having to load it.

If you write a LESS rule like normal without any of the mixins it will be put into both of these files and anything you add to with the `media-width()` mixin will be added before it, and therefore overwritten.

You can use the `@media-common = true` separation variable to output it only to *styles-m.css* before any of the media query rules are added.  This way it will be applied to both desktop and mobile devices, as both load *styles-m.css*.

`media-width()` mixins under 768px are only put in *styles-m.css*, vice-a-versa any `media-width()` mixins 768px over in width is only put in *styles-l.css*.

So, I think the best practice is to put all your common styles within `& when (@media-common = true) {}` and use the `media-width()` mixin for any css rules which are specific to a particular width.

For instance, below is what I went with in the end...

```
//
//  Common
//  _____________________________________________
& when (@media-common = true) {
  .logo img {
    width: 125px;
    height: 29px;
  }
}

//
//  Mobile
//  _____________________________________________
//.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'max') and (@break = @screen__m) {}

//
//  Desktop
//  _____________________________________________
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__m) {
  .logo img {
    width: 177px;
    height: 41px;
  }
}
```

It's the same approach used by Magento in:

- *app/design/frontend/Magento/blank/web/css/source/_navigation.less*
- *vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/source/_navigation.less*

Comment: well put! did you try having the nested styles inside the `media-common = true`? Given what you are finding, it might be possible to nest the media queries if you configure it differently then the way i have been doing it. Might be worth a try and see what the results are.

Comment: @circlesix just tried nesting  the `media-width()` mixin  within the `media-common = true` mixin and it didn't work.  It's not the way they do in the magento core either so I think it's best to keep it to the pattern above.

Comment: Awesome! Such a good explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Using the the core files as an example for how to use that mixin, i don't think you can have them nested in that way (even though i think that is the preferred way to use media queries).

Looking at a file in core like **vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/module/_collapsible_navigation.less**

```
//
//  Desktop
//  _____________________________________________

.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__m) {
    .block-collapsible-nav {
        .title {
            &:extend(.abs-visually-hidden-desktop all);
        }
    }
}

//
//  Mobile
//  _____________________________________________

.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'max') and (@break = @screen__m) {
    .block-collapsible-nav {
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: -21px;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 5;

        .title {
            &:extend(.abs-toggling-title-mobile all);
        }

        .content {
            border-bottom: @border-width__base solid @border-color__base;
            display: none;

            &.active {
                display: block;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You see that each css class is repeated into a media query container. I don't know if there is another way to do this, but i have stuck to this pattern and it works.

One thing that helps is to have very small `.less` files in your theme, as it reduces that amount of scrolling you have to do to find what you are looking for.